# TYPO3 v6.2.x Tutorials for beginners

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I  decided to learning TYPO3 v6.2.x CMS,I installed CMS on local server  but I can't create some basic  template, after long searching in google and here on stackoverflow, I can't find  any useful tutorials or books for beginners.

I need only tutorials  where explained how to create basic template  with TYPO3 CMS v6.x.x or maybe in "github" is some basic start kit with basic template?.

I hope some kind  people suggest me  how  and where to start.
Please don't be lazy, it`s very important for me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, TYPO3 v6.2 isn't supported anymore. I recommend you to start with v8. Not only because of the support but things have become more easy to use and extend in v8.7. Its also way faster while using php 7.1 ;)

There aren't a lot of tutorials. Most of the time learning TYPO3 is reviewing the core code and this site: http://docs.typo3.org/

The site also got an tutorial part (http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GuidesAndTutorials/Index.html) BTW.

But now to some of my recommendations:

> **EXT:styleguide** https://github.com/TYPO3/styleguide
>
> This extension is made by the core team to test everything in the
>   backend. Does not contain much of templating. But is definitely worth
>   a lot of looks ;)

Next one is more something you are looking for:

> **EXT:bootstrap_package** http://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/
>
> Also made by the core team. This extension brings bootstrap css based
>   frontend to TYPO3.

Hope you get some inspiration from this ;)
Happy Programming!

Kami Yang

Comment: Thank you very much Kami Yang!

Answer (score 0):

All Fluid tutorials should work. The official tutorial from typo3.org is
https://wiki.typo3.org/T3Doc/Fluidtemplate_by_example

There is also a "Bootstrap Kickstart Package". You can find it in the Extension Manager under "get preconfigured distribution". Or in the repository: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/bsdist

But why do you want to start learning with an old Version? End of maintenance of v6.2 was in April. Better start with the new LTS version 8.7.1

Comment: because i have old php version installed on my linux (php5.6)   and new  Type3 is required  php7, i have   a lot of project  and i am afraid to broke something  if i switch to php7 version

Comment: as long as your PHP 5.6 is up to date there is no problem to run TYPO3 7.6LTS which is still valid. on the other side: be aware of the lifetime/suppport time of your PHP and other applications, they will exceed in near future.

Answer (score 0):

My decision is to have a look on tutorial videos.

As said before, you should start at least with 7.6 LTS, so you start learning the way typo3 goes to future.

Start a small project using the "introduction package" which you can install via extensions->distributions.

The take a look at the backend & fronted and ask you questions, as they appear.

Answer (score 0):

[Typo3buddy](http://typo3buddy.com/typo3-template-tutorial/) is more useful tutorials for TYPO3 beginners, In this tutorials where explained in detials how to create basic template with Typo3 CMS.